# can react.js app do read/write operations on a json file in amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, single-page-application

my question is more of a theoretical question than a coding question...so on my **local server**, i did the read/write operations on the json file with React...everything works fine...if i build the app and upload whats inside the build folder to amazon S3 bucket i created, then used the bucket as a static hosted website and opened the provided URL

**will i still be able to manipulate that json file live ?!**

any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: So you want to use React app to change contents of a file, which is stored in an S3 bucket(that you have access to)?

Comment: on my local server, i use node.js as the web server, wrote a react.js app that manipulates content of a json file withing the react.js app files, works as expected on local server...will this approach work when i build and upload the react.js app on S3 bucket and serve the webapp from there?!